# Prevent enter to submit form / disable enter

Tags: 7, forms

I am trying to prevent to submit the form when a user is pressing enter. I am trying to do so in a form that is also using ajax. I want to have the user click on submit after filling out all the necessary stuff and not have them accidentally press enter and have the form submitted.

I have the code below; the alertbox is popping up when pressing 's' for example. also when I press enter I can get a alertbox popping up. But it is not preventing to submit the form.

```
$("#edit-searchfield").keydown(function(e){
  var code = e.which; // recommended to use e.which, it's normalized across browsers
  if (code == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
  if (code == 83 || code == 13 || code == 188 || code == 186) {
    alert("I am an alert box!");
  }
});
```

Comment: You need to disable button on page load and enable it back once form is filed completely

Comment: Can you pls provide me with an example on how to do that?

Comment: Something like this perhaps will work for you. http://jsfiddle.net/daudK/1/

Comment: Thanks for the example, but it doesn't prevent me from hitting the enter button .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the answer is :-)

```
$form['#attributes'] = array('onsubmit' => 'return false');
```

or alternatively (the above will disable submit all together)

```
  $('#edit-searchfield').keypress(function(event) {
   if (event.keyCode == '13') {
       event.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try jQuery's `submit()` event:

```
$('#my-form').submit(function(e) {
    if (/* the form is invalid */) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

That's better than adding `onsubmit` to `$form['#attributes']`. It's considered bad practice to mix your HTML and JavaScript that way =)

Answer (score 0):

Another alternate to achieve that is using the [Hide submit button](https://www.drupal.org/project/hide_submit) module

> Some users accidentally click the submit button more than once while waiting for their post to be saved. In some cases this may result duplicate postings or duplicate e-commerce orders.